# Can not access ConvexHull in Scipy 0.16.1

Tags: python, scipy

I was able to use the ConvexHull function in previous versions of Scipy. The function, in the version I had, would not provide the **Volume of the convex hull** so I decided to install the new version of Scipy. But after installing **Scipy 0.16.1** I noticed that the Spatial library is rearranged and now I get an error when trying to call ConvexHull function.

This code would work in previous versions of Scipy:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
X = np.random.randint(0,200,(30,2))
hull = sp.spatial.qhull.Delaunay(X).convex_hull
```

Now, for the code above, I get the error:

> AttribureError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spatial'.

It seems there is nothing inside .qhull.
I have checked this in VS,Spider,Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly import the spatial subpackage. This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial
X = np.random.randint(0,200,(30,2))
hull = sp.spatial.qhull.Delaunay(X).convex_hull
```

Comment: Now I get this error:
from ._sparetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobst, csr_count_blocks, \ ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: This error tell you that the scipy package was not installed correctly. There could be multiple reasons for that: Compiling the package failed, you did not install the correct binaries, and probably more. I would see if reinstalling scipy helps. If not, you will have to provide more information in order do get a good answer.